# What does mcs stand for in VTUNE?

Tags: windows-xp, c++, vtune

I am using Vtune (9.1) and noticed that it says things like "Self Time 103,425 mcs" - but what does mcs stand for? If I search in the help system I get no results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is MiCroSeconds.  It is usually written us or more properly µs.
(1 µs = 0.000001s)